# Finding Touched elments CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor, range, nodes

I am looking several days now on the web, but i can't seem to find out, how i can find if the caret is touching a element. Let me explain myself a little better with this example.

```
This is a[ ] <span>example</span>
```

As Example we say that the caret is the tag [ ].
And now we like to know if the caret is near a span element?
How can we find this? Also I need to know if the span element is before or after the caret.

I'm doing this with the CKEDITOR 4.0 api..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var range = CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.getSelection().getRanges()[ 0 ];
range.optimize();
console.log( range.getBoundaryNodes() );
```

Also:

```
console.log( range.getTouchedEndNode() );
console.log( range.getTouchedStartNode() );
```

Note that your range may be located inside of an element (like **e4**, image below), so boundary nodes will always be text nodes. Check [DOM range specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) for more.

[image]

---

EDIT: These are also worth trying:

```
range.getNextNode();
range.getPreviousNode();
```

---

After all, once you have the node, you can check it:

```
var node = range.getNextNode();
console.log( node.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && node.is( 'span' ) );
```

Comment: I think that getNextNode will do the job. But getNextSourceNode() didn't do the job and get Next doesn't return anything at all in InternetExplorer? What is the difference between this 3? (I will confirm in a moment.. first will complete a few more tests)

Comment: After all the getNextNode and getPreviousNode functions are the solution.. I would appreciate explanation about the difference of the 3.. tnx!

Comment: [node.getNextSourceNode()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node-method-getNextSourceNode) and [node.getNext()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node-method-getNext) are methods of **[CKEDITOR.dom.node](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node)**. 

What you need, since you deal with selection, are methods of [CKEDITOR.dom.range](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range).