# CKEditor end/start of tag detect

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

In my Previous post: 
[Finding Touched elments CKEDITOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084648/finding-touched-elments-ckeditor),
I was looking for the touched elements. The anwser at that post worked well.

But now i am having another problem. When the caret is set to the Front or the end of a tag/block. 
I only can see that the parent is span. But it can be that the user tried to put the caret just outside the tag. example:

```
this ^<span>^test</span> text
```

The caret can be set to both "^" without seeing any difference.

(Single selection (startContainer == endContainer))

The anwser on the previous post does detect the span if it is just outside the tag. But just inside the tag it won't detect which gives a new scenario.. i Need a way to avoid the new scenario and let it handle like a touched block.

I would like to detect if the caret is inside the span and do touch the start. 
The same for the end only then it would touch the end. 
The function range.checkStartOfBlock returns false, this isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for Mozilla, now i also want a fix for IE7 and up.

Mozilla fix:
A check for start:

```
range.startOffset === 0 //Means StartOfBlock
```

A Check for end:

```
range.endOffset === range.startContainer.getText().length //Means EndOfBlock
```

==== Edit ====

The rangy range library from rangy.googlecode.com provided an acceptable solution. 
(the offer a somehow compatible startOffset and some other functionalities.)
I needed about 3 checks for Internet Explorer and only 1 for Mozilla. 
But it looks like it's fool proof.

Still all ideas are very welcome.